# function return only 1 result in a while

Tags: php

I would like to have a select with all the uploads files in the folder. I creat a function :

```
if (!defined('select_uploads')) 
{
    function select_uploads()
    {
        $adresse="partials/rapport_qualite/uploads/"; //Adresse du dossier.
        $dossier=Opendir($adresse); //Ouverture du dossier.

        while ($Fichier = readdir($dossier))
        {
             if ($Fichier != "." && $Fichier != "..") // Filtre anti-point ! 
             {
                 return '<option value="'.$Fichier.'">'.$Fichier.'</option>';
             }   
        }
    }
}
```

With this function i have only one result and not all the files.

Comment: return breaks the loop ... so use another logic

Comment: One more thing, when reading the files from a directory, you really should be testing against `FALSE`, rather than checking a falsey value. A file called `0` or `false` will break out of your loop prematurely: `if (($fichier = readdir($dossier)) !== FALSE) { ... }`.

Comment: Well done,  I added the test. Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now when the `if` condition is satisfied it will return that particular option and `break` the `loop` and `function`.
You should create a `string` with all the `option`s and then `return` the `string` -

```
    $options = '';
    while ($Fichier = readdir($dossier))
    {
         if ($Fichier != "." && $Fichier != "..") // Filtre anti-point ! 
         {
             $options.= '<option value="'.$Fichier.'">'.$Fichier.'</option>';
         }   
    }
    return $options;
```

[RETURN](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP >= 5.5.0, then you can turn your function into a generator

```
if (!defined('select_uploads')) 
{
    function select_uploads()
    {
        $adresse="partials/rapport_qualite/uploads/"; //Adresse du dossier.
        $dossier=Opendir($adresse); //Ouverture du dossier.

        while ($Fichier = readdir($dossier))
        {
             if ($Fichier != "." && $Fichier != "..") // Filtre anti-point ! 
             {
                 yield '<option value="'.$Fichier.'">'.$Fichier.'</option>';
             }   
        }
    }
}

foreach(select_uploads() as $fileUpload) {
    echo $fileUpload;
}
```

Though it's cleaner to move the markup out of your select_uploads() and into the foreach loop instead

Comment: You do realise that PHP 5.4 is end of life within the next two months, and that even PHP 5.5 is security fixes only?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a return statement, then the result will be returned and after that, the loop will not run. So you have to concatenate all the results to a string and return that one.
Try like this

```
if (!defined('select_uploads')) 
{
    $tempvar='';
    function select_uploads()
    {
    $adresse="partials/rapport_qualite/uploads/"; //Adresse du dossier.
    $dossier=Opendir($adresse); //Ouverture du dossier.

    while ($Fichier = readdir($dossier))
    {
         if ($Fichier != "." && $Fichier != "..") // Filtre anti-point ! 
         {
             $tempvar.'= '<option value="'.$Fichier.'">'.$Fichier.'</option>';
         }   
    }
    }
return $tempvar;
}
```